# IndexError: list index out of range in a while loop

Tags: python

```
def remove_triplets(a_list):
    i = len(a_list)
    while 1 < i:
        if a_list[i] == a_list[i - 1] and a_list[i] == a_list[i - 2]:
            a_list = a_list[:i - 3]
            i = i - 3
        else:
            i = i - 1
    return a_list

print(remove_triplets([3, 3, 3]))
```

I don't know how to set the conditions of the while loop so line 4 won't have out of range errors.

Comment: can you explain what your code is doing?

Comment: This function seems to remove any elements past the *first* occurrence of a triplet. There is no point scanning through all occurrences from the back.

Answer (score 2):

```
i = len(a_list)
```

and then

```
a_list[i]
```

cause error. Maybe you want `i = len(a_list) - 1` or so. Hard to tell because it's not clear what you aim to do.

General suggestion: in such cases try checking the variables in problematic line. In this case that would be adding:

```py
        print(a[i])
        print(a[i-1])
        print(a[i-2])
```

and you should spot the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
a_list[len(a_list)]
```

This is your problem. Lists are zero indexed and so the last item in a list is indexed as len(your_list) - 1.